# does not find rjs file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rjs

I am using rails 2.3.8 and I'll load a modal dialog box using a partial called _show_venue.html.erb. Inside this partial I add link_to_remote to edit each venue.

_show_venue.html.erb ::

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Place</th>
<th>Color</th>
</tr>

<% @venues.each do |venue| %>
<tr>
<td><%=h venue.country_id %></td>
<td><%=h venue.place %></td>
<td><%=h venue.color %></td>

<td><%= link_to_remote 'Edit', :url => {:controller => 'venues', :action => 'edit', :id=>venue.id } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

And this is my controller code ::

```
def edit
@venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
end
```

edit.js.rjs ::

```
page.replace_html 'edit_venue', :partial => 'edit_form'
page<< "$j ('#event_actions').dialog({
    title: 'Edit venue
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $j ('#event_actions').dialog('destroy') }
});"
```

But when I run this, it could not find edit.js.rjs file. Why did this happen? Anyone can explain it?

Comment: where is edit.js.rjs in the file structure?

Comment: app/views/venue..  I have folder called venue and all rjs and html files are there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following changes to you controller method:

```
respond_to do |format|    
      format.js      
end
```

so that it will find the edit.js.rjs and render it.

Edit: The 404 HTTP status which was the main problem was because of a missing route.

A route to match venues/:id/edit should solve the problem.

Comment: well, are you sure your routes etc are proper, because it works for me.

Comment: do you get some error ? can you paste the stack trace for that action call.

Comment: Yaah... I tried to load two modal dialog boxes. I already load one modal dialog box and that edit link is inside this modal dialog box. something wrong with this?

Comment: Strange, with 404 i would expect some thing on the stack trace. I would say something is wrong with the routing. Keeping the edit link in a modal dialog should not matter afaik.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3885/discussion-between-alokswain-and-rosh)

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file  `edit.js.rjs` to `edit.rjs`

Edited

I think you have to do it other way as you want dynamic object `@venue`,
 Try following

```
def edit
  @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html 'edit_venue', :partial => 'edit_form', :object => @venue
    page<< "$j ('#event_actions').dialog({
      title: 'Edit venue
      modal: true,
      width: 500,
      close: function(event, ui) { $j ('#event_actions').dialog('destroy') }
    });"
   end
 end
```

your link should be as follows [you have to write `:method` ]

```
<%= link_to_remote 'Edit', :url => {:controller => 'venues', :action => 'edit', :id=>venue.id }, :method=>'put' %>
```

you can also try 'post' if above doesn't work

Comment: It did not find edit.rjs I got 404 Not Found ... what should I do?

Comment: I tried it. But it did not work... Is something wrong with this <%= link_to_remote 'Edit', :url => {:controller => 'venues', :action => 'edit', :id=>venue.id } %> ?

Answer (score 0):

rename edit.js.rjs to edit.js.erb

Add the following to the end of your edit method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
```

restart your server